# Find the limit of the sequence $a_n=n\sin{\frac{\pi}{2n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit of the sequence
$$a_n=n\sin{\frac{\pi}{2n}}$$

I would like to know how to find this limit. The question says the answer is $\pi/2$, but I've failed to find this result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is equivalent to the following
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2n} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2n} \right)}{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ (\pi/2) \cdot \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2n} \right)}{\pi/2n}$$

A common limit is

$$\lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{\sin(1/a)}{1/a} \xrightarrow{a \mapsto 1/u} \lim_{u \to 0^+} \frac{\sin(u)}{u} = 1 $$

Clearly, we can cancel in the below limit

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ (\pi/2) \cdot \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2n} \right)}{\pi/2n} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 5):

We have that $\frac{\pi}{2n} \to 0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1$

Using these,we have that:

$$n\sin{\frac{\pi}{2n}}=\frac{\frac{\pi}{2} \sin{\frac{\pi}{2n}}}{\frac{\pi}{2n}} \to \frac{\pi}{2} \times 1=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 4):

$\sin(\pi/2n)\sim \frac{\pi}{2n}$ for large $n$ by first order Taylor's.

Thus your limit 
$$
n\frac{\pi}{2n}=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$